# When call zbar scanner from a button, the app freezes

Tags: navigation, freeze, drawer, zbar

I have an app with a Navigation drawer. The navigation drawer has a table with a number of cells. When the user presses a table cell, the value is store in a singleton and the drawer closes and the main screen appears.

When the main screen loads, in the viewDidLoad function, the code checks the values stored in the singleton and if there is a certain value, it call a zbar scanner.
But the drawer never closes it just hangs. I can see from debug that the value has been passed to the singleton and accessed correctly in the viewDidload function.

//This is the code in viewDidLoad. shareData is the singleton, varView stores the value of the table selected in the Navigation drawer. "zero is printed out to the debug console but then there is a hang
        if(self.shareData.varView == 0) 
        {
            print("zero")

```
        scanWaitingFunction()

    }
```

Also when the zbar scanner is called from a button press in the main screen, it works correctly. I have tried to call the button programatically from the viewDidLoad function but the drawer never closes and the app freezes.
 @IBAction func scan(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    scanWaitingFunction()
}

Also
  func scanWaitingFunction()
    {

```
     locked = true
    scanner()         //wait for the async method, the zbar scanner to complete before advancing
    while(locked){wait()}

        }
func wait()
{
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1))
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using the SWRevealViewController Library

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem does not occur when a view controller (zbar scanner) is called when then navigation drawer is close(swrevealcontroller).

When the navigation drawer is open, the hang occurs

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding a time delay between when the navigation drawer is dismissed and the scanner view controller is presented

```
let seconds = 2.0
let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            let rvc = self.revealViewController()
            rvc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)                

        })
  scanWaitingFunction()
```